# How can I specify the return type of a NestJs controller with a Sequelize-Typescript model definition?

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I tried:

```
    @Post()
    async create(@Body() body: CreateStreamDto): Promise<typeof Stream> {
        return { id: '12', connectionUrl: 'stuff' }
    }
```

But it says:

```
ype '{ id: string; connectionUrl: string; }' is not assignable to type 'typeof Stream'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'typeof Stream'.
```

Comment: What is `Stream`? What are you trying to return here?

Comment: It's a `sequelize-typescript` defined model:
```
@Table
export class Stream extends Model<Stream> {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are returning an instance of a model, you should just need `Promise<Stream>`. `typeof Stream` will probably return `Object` or something similar, which will be why you are getting the above error.